# .htaccess redirect ajax request with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I'd like to redirect an ajax request which includes two parameters to a specific page.
this is my folder structure:

```
.
+-- index.php
|
+-- /js/functions.js
|
+-- /pages/projects.php
|     +
|     +-- /projects-list/1.example.php
|
+-- /duo/index.php
```

in order to display 1.example.php:
I request ../pages/projects.php from index.php via the following ajax function (/js/function.js):

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../pages/projects',
  success: function( response ) {
   // load the response
  }
});
```

and I change the url to

http://localhost:8888/index.php?page=pages/projects

once I'm here I have a link which submits another ajax request to load /pages/projects-list/1.example.php:

```
$.ajax({
  url: './pages/projects.php',
  data: 'project=project-list/1.example',
  success: function( response ) {
   // load the response
  }
});
```

the resulting url is then:

http://localhost:8888/index.php?page=pages/projects&project=project-list/1.example

How do I redirect this page to: /duo/index.php via .htaccess?
From the network tab it seems that the request is handled by projects.php so I tried:

```
#Redirect example
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRNG} project=project-list/1.example
RewriteRule ^projects\.php$ /duo/? [L,R=301]
```

but it doesn't work...
thanks!

## if needed:

I'm manually changing the url via:

```
function ChangeUrl(page, url) {
  if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
    var obj = { Page: page, Url: url };
    // console.log(obj);
    history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
  }
}
```

so that I can reload the page which contains the dynamic elements I loaded via ajax)